# Arch Linux - Archiso - Implement custom commands after installation

Tags: linux, command-line, installation, arch-linux

I'm creating a new Arch Linux-based ISO by using [Archiso](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/archiso).
My purpose is to run commands as:

```
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --populate
```

after the installation, so, in the Live Environment, because I need to set keys of unofficial repositories (where the public keys are stored in `airootfs/usr/share/pacman/keyrings/`), otherwise I'll get pacman key error during the first `sudo pacman -Syy` command in the Live Environment.

According to the Archiso documentation (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/archiso), it is not specified how to run custom commands on the new created environment. Time ago I read the user could add commands in a custom script `airootfs/root/customize_airootfs.sh` but this method is deprecated so I prefer to avoid it.

In `airootfs/root/` folder I see two files, `.zlogin` and `.automated_script.sh` but even if I edit them by adding custom commands, not seem they are executing after the installation, and I don't know who should call `.zlogin` script.

Could you please provide me some suggestions for reaching this purpose?

Thanks